# Access directive object (this) in link function | ES6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, this, ecmascript-6

Is there a way one can access the directive's object inside its link function?
I am porting code to ES6. And this one is failing for me when I try to access the directive object inside its link function.

```
class myDirective {
    constructor($parse) {
        //DDO properties
        this.restrict = "A";
        this.scope = {};
        this.controllerAs = "SomeCtrl";
        this.controller = "SomeCtrl";
        this.bindToController = true;

        this.$parse = $parse;
    }

    link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(this);  //<== the link function is not called in context of myDirective object and logs "window" instead of myDirective

        // Do something with $parse
        // This is not working as this.$parse is not available on window obv
        let foo = this.$parse("baz");
    }

    // Create an instance so that we can access this inside link
    static directiveFactory($parse) {
        myDirective.instance = new myDirective($parse);
        return myDirective.instance;
    }
}

// Inject dependencies
myDirective.directiveFactory.$inject = ["$parse"];

export default myDirective.directiveFactory;
```

I try to avoid private variables that sit outside of the class and hope there is a better way to get hold of the directive object.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why link isn't bound to the right variable, so I consider this a workaround, but what if you use the 4th argument passed to the link function (`ctrl`) - since you have `bindToController` then that should be the same as `this`, no?

Comment: No. It actually isn't the same. When logging ```ctrl``` inside the directive's link function I get, well, the attached controller but not the directive object that's being constructed from  ```class myDirective()```, eg. ```this.$parse …```

Comment: Ah, fair enough. How are you actually instantiating one of these directives? I presume with `new myDirective()`?

Comment: ```import MyDirective from "./myDirective.directive";```

And then …

```angular.module("app", []).directive("myDirective", MyDirective).controller(…);```

Comment: Okay, to be honest I'm not really sure how angular works with classes, does angular call `new` on that? My concern is that it might just treat it as a function and not actually instantiate it, which might explain why you have the wrong `this` context. What about if you pass `new MyDirective()` as the second argument to `.directive`?

Comment: Well, it gets instantiated as I export the static function ```static directiveFactory($parse)```. And this one gets called on bootstrapping (and returns the directive instance).

Comment: If `this` doesn't refer to the instance, it's because you are not calling `link` properly. Since you don't show how you call it, there is not much we can do about it.

Comment: @FelixKling See my second comment, this is how I call it – I import the directive (the directive instance that is being returned by its static directiveFactory) and pass it to the Angular modules directive call. A proof that even the simplest link function yields ```this === window``` http://jsbin.com/wakudasowa/3/edit And that is correct because the function is evaluated in Angular's context.

Comment: Ah I guess I don't know enough about AngularJS ;)

Answer (score 2):

Doh! I just realised that my static field is available in the link function (obv!).

```
link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    console.log(myDirective.instance); // This now logs my directive instance and I can access its properties.
    …
}
```